# Implementing PStore sessions in Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

Please understand that I'm asking HOW one would implement PStore sessions (or any other custom session storage) in Rails3 and not WHY.  Hopefully this will curb the responses like, "*You buffoon - you should never use x, use y!*"  Let's just say I'm trying to prove a point that it can be done.  However, I can't seem to do it.

I know that I at least have to define my custom session storage class.  Below are the contents of ./initializers/session_store.rb

session_store.rb:

```
class ActionDispatch::Session::PStore
  def call(h)
    ...no idea what should go here?
  end
end

MyApp::Application.config.session_store :p_store
```

Ideas? Solutions?

Comment: +1 for spelling buffoon correctly. I see that word misspelled all the time.

Comment: Well, that's one thing I've done right today! No help on this yet... I'll even take MemoryStore if that's known.

Comment: If you look at [v3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb) and [3.0.10](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb) abstract_store.rb source you will see that the implementation seemed to have changed. 

v3.0.10 override some methods [redis-session-store example](https://github.com/mattmatt/redis-session-store/blob/master/lib/redis-session-store.rb). The v3.1 implementation seems to use Mixins haven't found an example...